# Undefined bhaviour with usage of union in cpp?

Tags: c++, unions

I'm working on union using c++,
following is code snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef union myunion
{
  double PI;
  int B;
}MYUNION;

int main()
{
  MYUNION numbers;
  numbers.PI = 3;
  numbers.B = 50;
  cout <<" numbers.PI :" << numbers.PI << endl;
  if(numbers.PI == 3.0)
  {
      cout <<"True";
    if(numbers.B == 50)
    {
      cout <<" numbers.PI :" << numbers.PI << endl;
       cout <<" numbers.B :" << numbers.B << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
 numbers.PI :3
```

Even value of numbers.PI is set to 3 already, first "if" condition yields to false.
what is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Coding tip: `typedef union myunion { ... } MYUNION;` is a C-style approach, totally unnecessary in C++. Just do `union MYUNION { ... };` if you want it called like that. In C++, `struct`, `union` and `class` names share the same space of names as other identifiers, so you don't have to prefix them with the `struct` (or other) keyword, as you do in C.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that there's no reason.

Your code invokes undefined behavior because you are setting the `B` member of the union:

```
numbers.B = 50;
```

but immediately after setting it, you read out **the other member,** `PI`:

```
cout <<" numbers.PI :" << numbers.PI << endl;
```

Maybe **you are confusing unions and structures** - unless the floating-point number `3` and the integer `50` have the very same bit representation on your architecture (which is very unlikely), the behavior you expect from your program would be reasonable only if you used a `struct` instead.

(`union` members reside at the same place in memory - setting one overwrites the other too. This is not true for a `struct`, which has each of its members stored at a different memory location.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I know I'm setting B member of union, then in that case even after setting this value, How union is able to print the value of PI correctly?

Comment: @BSalunke Again, undefined behavior. Your program is free to do anything it pleases - including behaving seemingly correctly, crashing, wiping your hard disk, or launching a rocket into outer space.

Comment: @BSalunke In this particular case, it might happen that after doing `PI = 3`, the value was left in a register, and as there were no intermittent writes to `PI`, the compiler just optimised out the read from memory for the output. At the same time, the output operation is complex enough to modify registers, so a new read has to happen for the immediately following comparison. But I'm just guessing; as H2CO3 points out, with UB, anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that all members of a union shares the same memory. When you assign to `B` you change the value of `PI` as well.

To be safe, you should only "read" from the last field you "write" to.

It seems to me that what you want is a structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting undefined behavior, but here's what is happening behind the scenes:

You're using a little-endian machine with sizeof(int) < sizeof(double), such as an x86.  Almost certainly, the machine uses IEEE 754 format for floats/double (pretty much all machines do these days).

When you write into the B field, it overwrites the low order bits of the double in PI.  So
when you initially store 3.0 in `PI`, that sets it to something like `0x4008000000000000`.  Then when you store 50 in `B` that changes `PI` to `0x4008000000000032`, which happens to be 3.00000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625.  So that's not equal to 3.0, but when you print it with default precision, it rounds it to 3.0